# Get string length that is created dynamically

Tags: powershell

Lets say I want to do something like this:

```
$string = 'arbitrary string' # << is random
(Do-Something -Name ($string + (Get-Random)).Substring(0, [math]::Min(20, ??)
```

How do I refer to current length of the result of the expression inside `($string + (Get-Random))`?

Fails when using `Substring(0, 20)` when string shorter than 20 chars

> Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Index and length
>   must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to assign the new string to a variable:

```
Do-Something -Name ($s = $string + (Get-Random)).Substring(0, [math]::Min(20,$s.Length))
```

A less terse version of the above:

```
$Name = $string + (Get-Random)
if($Name.Length -gt 20){
    $Name = $Name.Substring(0, 20)
}
Do-Something -Name $Name
```

As mentioned in the comments, you could also select the first 20 chars by index from the string and combine again with the `-join` operator (v3.0 and newer):

```
$Name = "$string$(Get-Random)"[0..19] -join ''
```

Feeling frisky? Use regex (as [suggested by wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42435575/get-string-length-that-is-created-dynamically/42435701?noredirect=1#comment72017036_42435701)):

```
$Name = "$string$(Get-Random)" -replace '^(.{20}).+','$1'
```

If the concatenated string is less than 20 characters nothing will be replaced, otherwise the entire string will match and get replaced by the first 20 characters

Another approach would be to generate a random number of X digits where X is 20 - `$string.Length` (only works if `$string` is guaranteed to be between 2 and 19 characters long):

```
$Name = "$string$(Get-Random -Min ('1' * (20 - $string.Length)) -Max ('9' * (20 - $string.Length)))"
```

Comment: well, I didn't even think about this

Comment: @4c74356b41 Now you do :-)

Comment: btw, is there any other way, this seems a bit hackish? ;)

Comment: I can think of other ways, like `("$string$(random)"[0..19]-join'')`, but not any that seems less hackish

Comment: Another hack: `"$string$(Get-Random)" -replace '(?s)^(.{20}).+','$1'`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I've added `(?s)` to make `.` match new line characters as well.

Comment: @4c74356b41 added a few more examples (all even more hackish though) ;-)